# Ajax send FormData and retrieve multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Alright so I have a form where you select a CSV file and when you hit the sales_importer button I would like my java to call my php function and get the returned multidimensional array to then do later processing. When I run the following code I get the alert box with a multidimensional array of values but it seems like it is in string form. When I do `alert(result[0][0]);` I get `[` in my alert box.

I have tried changing my dataType in my ajax call to json but then it just fails but I still get a 200 response from my browser. Any suggestions of what might be going on/how to go about fixing it?

**js**

```
$('body').on('click', '#sales_importer', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData($('form[id="import_form"]')[0]),
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false, 
        url: admin_url+'Clients/import',
        success: function(result){    
            alert(result);                      
        }
    }); 
});
```

**php**

```
public function import()
{
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        if (isset($_FILES['client_file_csv']['name']) && $_FILES['client_file_csv']['name'] != '') {            
            // Get the temp file path
            $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['client_file_csv']['tmp_name'];
            // Make sure we have a filepath
            if (!empty($tmpFilePath) && $tmpFilePath != '') { 
                // Setup our new file path
                $newFilePath = TEMP_FOLDER . $_FILES['client_file_csv']['name'];

                if (!file_exists(TEMP_FOLDER)) {
                    mkdir(TEMP_FOLDER, 777);
                }
                if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) { 
                    $import_result = true;
                    $fd            = fopen($newFilePath, 'r');
                    $rows          = array();
                    while ($row = fgetcsv($fd)) {
                        $rows[] = $row;
                    }
                    $data['total_rows_post'] = count($rows);
                    fclose($fd);                           

                    echo json_encode($rows); 
                }
                unlink($newFilePath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might try serializing and logging the content of $rows to your server so you can inspect what is being returned in the response.

Comment: @BrianGottier When I serialize the response to a log this is the beginning of the response. a:520:{i:0;a:16:{i:0;s:10:"company";i:1;s:11:"phonenumber";i:2;s:8:"main_fax";i:3;s:13:"vehiclenumber";i:4;s:4:"city";i:5;s:5:"state";i:6;s:7:"address";i:7;s:6:"county";i:8;s:3:"zip";i:9;s:7:"Website";i:10;s:13:"Agency Status";i:11;s:16:"Inside Sales Rep";i:12;s:17:"Outside Sales Rep";i:13;s:5:"Notes";i:14;s:21:"Other Agency Comments";i:15;s:10:"Record ID#";}

Comment: I have no clue what the i,a and s are for but the first row of the CSV does say: company,phonenumber,main_fax,vehiclenumber,etc... Also, if I print it json_encoded vs serialized I get: [["\ufeffcompany","phonenumber","main_fax","vehiclenumber","city","state","address","county","zip","Website","Agency Status","Inside Sales Rep","Outside Sales Rep","Notes","Other Agency Comments","Record ID#"], ... etc

Comment: Looks like fgetcsv isn't splitting the fields on the quotes. Could be an encoding issue in your csv file. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8294632/3585500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to use the data in javascript, then you're going to need to apply a key. So in your PHP:

```
echo json_encode( array('rows' => $rows) );
```

This now allows you to access the rows in your jQuery AJAX success function:

```
success: function(result){    
    // rows available as result.rows
    if( result.rows ){
        // Do something with result.rows...
        console.log( result.rows );
        $.each( result.rows, function(i, arr){
             console.log( arr );
        });
    }                     
}
```

Remember that result.rows is going to be a javascript object, so you'll need to use jQuery's each to loop through the rows and do what you want to do. Use your console to view result.rows, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: When I do this I get nothing written in the console. If I add `else{console.log("no");}` I get "no" in my console so it doesn't seem like it is getting anything in result.rows.

Comment: Is move_uploaded_file actually saving the file to $newFilePath?

Comment: Yeah, I even checked the new file path and the file is there. I even spit out the array to a view and can see the data. There is something weird going on with the whole ajax transaction.

Comment: You should try using the jQuery ajax setting dataType: 'json'

Comment: When I add dataType: 'json' the ajax actually kicks to error instead of success

Comment: What's the error? Since you're expecting json, all you're telling jQuery is that the response should be json. I'm going to guess that because json is a comma delimited type of object, and you are trying to pass back csv data, that it's corrupted and/or just not playing well. What is it that you're trying to do? Maybe we can think of a better solution than passing back the CSV data?

Comment: Alright so here was the issue. I'm using codeigniter so my php function I have doing different things depending on the request. In this case I had it check if the input was an ajax request but for some reason after I was echoing my response it was continuing on to where I use the function to load my view. So the response was getting the data along with html junk which was probably corrupting it. I thought once you echoed a response that was the end of it but I guess not...

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151918/discussion-between-brian-gottier-and-tyler-fontaine).